# This page isn’t working: HTTP ERROR 500 joomla on the front end

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have hosted my joomla website by uploading all my files to public_html, I have also changed the connections for host, user name, password and database name to the according. But when I run my front end, I see

**This page isn’t working
domain name is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500**

Please help

Comment: Does the back-end work?

Answer (score 5):

Some things to try:

1. Using FTP or similar, temporarily rename `.htaccess` to `.htaccess.old` and copy `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess` in the root folder of your website so you are using the default .htaccess file.
2. Using FTP or similar, edit your `configuration.php` file and set `public $error_reporting = 'maximum';` to see if there are any more meaningful error messages.
3. Temporarily rename any `php.ini` files in the root folder of your website.
4. Repeat steps 1 and 3 in the `/administration` folder if the back end of the website is also affected.
5. In cPanel or similar, try switching PHP 7.x back to PHP 5.6 if applicable. You may have some extensions that are not ready for PHP 7 yet.
6. Clear the cache by manually deleting everything in the `/cache` folder. Also clear the cache in the hosting control panel, in your CDN e.g. CloudFlare and anywhere else if these options exist.
7. Create and upload a simple `index.html` page to see if the hosting is operational.
8. Create and upload a simple `index.php` page to see if php is working (temporarily rename the current `index.php` to `index.old`).
9. Check folder and file permissions. Folders should be 755 and files should be 644.
10. Try restoring a copy of the website to an alternative local or remote host to see if the problem is with the hosting or if the website is broken somehow.
11. Try accessing the website via a temporary url rather than the domain name to see if the issue is with the domain name. For example, some hosts allow you to access your website via the IP address and cPanel account name like this: `http://123.123.123.123/~acctname`
12. Disable third party extensions one by one by editing the `xxx_extensions` table using phpMyAdmin or similar until the site works again or until all third party extensions are disabled.
13. In PHP Selector in cPanel or similar, check that the relevant PHP modules are enabled. PHP 5.6 will look something like this:

[image: PHP 5.6 Options]

14. Assuming nothing else works, assuming you have a current backup and assuming you haven't edited any of the core code, you could try uploading and expanding the full install package for your current version of Joomla e.g. `Joomla_3.8.6-Stable-Full_Package.zip` in the root folder of your website to overwrite any corrupt files. Once expanded, delete the install package and the `/installation` folder.

Hopefully one of these suggestions will help. Unfortunately there are many potential causes of "Error 500".

Comment: I have tried all this, but still experiencing the same error. problem. Do you have another suggestion. Another question am I suppose to have the index.html page or what?

Comment: OK, I've added a few more.

Comment: Greetings again. So if the public_html folder, and it asks me to install joomla, as I would do in the localhost. Is it fine if I follow the steps again. Because that is what the hosting site is suggesting. But then how do I upload the one I have already created if that is the case. Do I extract and replace my files, with the ones from the joomla site I just installed??

Comment: tried step 3 and getting  
Fatal error: Call to undefined method  JApplicationAdministrator::isClient() in /home/sites/5a/6/64453ca97b/public_html/plugins/system/logout/logout.php on line 48 as error msg

Answer (score 5):

I would like to add one more point in Neil Robertson is as below:

By doing point no 2 - (enabling error reporting) still the issue persist, Please check the public $gzip; variable in configuration file. It should be 0 as Joomla internally does the gzip compression.

Excuse my Grammar :( Novice in English.

Comment: the public $gzip is already set as 0. I am still experiencing the same error. Another question I have is that, shouldn't the hosting site already have created for me an index.html page as well as an error.html file....

Comment: By Reading the your comment on Neil Robertson answer, Got to know you trying to install joomla on production and also you have your site on your local machine. If you want to install local copy code on production site then you should use Akeeba Backup for the same. So you need to follow below steps.  1. Install akeeba on local site, 2. Run the backup , 3. upload on production servers public_html folder, 4. Run akeeba restore steps and your site will be up. You can check all the detailed information related akeeba here.https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/akeeba-backup-documentation.html

Comment: Yeah sure Let me know if you need any help, Happy to do it :)

Comment: Yes you need to Download it and upload it, This video can help you more https://www.akeebabackup.com/videos/1212-akeeba-backup-core/1618-abtc04-restore-site-new-server.html

Comment: Is this solved ? On which steps you faced this issues ?? On running kickstart.php file ? Let me know which steps you faced this so i can tell you what would be the issue

Comment: I followed the video tutorial and every step worked using kickstart..php file and the Akeeba-backup, then clicked on the cleanup button. Then started experiencing the HTTP Error 500 as soon as the site loaded. And then I tried Neil step 3 solution of putting maximum on error reporting,and got Fatal error: Call to undefined method JApplicationAdministrator::isClient() in /home/sites/5a/6/64453ca97b/public_html/plugins/system/logout/logout.php on line 48 as error msg. Then I tried  to host with another web hosting domain and it ran fine with no errors

Comment: Strange :) So is it solved now or not ? Which Joomla version you are using ?

Comment: Problem is I can't host because I have already made a one year contract with the web hosting company. So problem not solved. For my site to make the website, I was using joomla 3.8.1. With the hosting site, it installs joomla 3.6.4.

Comment: Ohh , So you had deleted all files related with 3.6.4  ? and as you have used akeeba your all 3.8.1 files will be there in public_html ? As this thread going bit long , we can take this off the stack , You can contact me on my personal email sudhirjsapkal@gmail.com, we will talk there and solve your problem , it will be something minor thing which making you trouble :)